# How to test a stub returning a promise in an async test?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, promise, sinon

How can I test this in a async manner?

```
it('Should test something.', function (done) {

    var req = someRequest,
        mock = sinon.mock(response),
        stub = sinon.stub(someObject, 'method');

     // returns a promise
     stub.withArgs('foo').returns(Q.resolve(5));

     mock.expects('bar').once().withArgs(200);

     request(req, response);

     mock.verify();

});
```

And here is the method to test.

```
var request = function (req, response) {

    ...

    someObject.method(someParameter)
        .then(function () {
            res.send(200);
        })
        .fail(function () {
            res.send(500);
        });

};
```

As you can see I am using node.js, Q (for the promise), sinon for mocking and stubbing and mocha as the test environment. The test above fails because of the async behaviour from the request method and I don't know when to call done() in the test.

Comment: Easiest way i found in working with async calls, when you want to use the response, was to break the function in 2 at the point where the response is needed and call the second part when the response is received.

Comment: you need to choose an answer, not just upvote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call done once all the async operations have finished. When do you think that would be? How would you normally wait until a request is finished?

```
it('Should test something.', function (done) {

   var req = someRequest,
       mock = sinon.mock(response),
       stub = sinon.stub(someObject, 'method');

    // returns a promise
    stub.withArgs('foo').returns(Q.resolve(5));

    mock.expects('bar').once().withArgs(200);

    request(req, response).then(function(){
       mock.verify();
       done();
    });

});
```

It might also be a good idea to mark your test as failing in an errorcallback attached to the request promise.

Comment: The request method is not a promise for itself. So there is no .then method to call. I would wait until response.send is called. Unfortunately the request method terminates before that happens.

Comment: Maybe the core of this problem didn't came out quiet good. I usually yield the callback from someObject.method like so `stub.withArgs('foo').yields(5)`. In this case the callback function is getting executed immediately. But now, with promises, I only return a deferred object and the resolve and reject handler get called to late because the request method has already terminated. Therefor the mock objects didn't get verified. If I wrap the verify method in a setTimeout with a call to done with it the test passes. `setTimeout(function () { mock.verify(); done(); }, 100)`

Comment: Hmm, in my experience it's good practice for asynchronous methods to provide some way of knowing when they will complete - to do this you can either accept a callback parameter, or return a promise. Depending which method you use, you can call the "end of test" code there.

Comment: You are right, if I do want to use promisses then I need to implement the responses send method with a call to done in it. But in that case I can forget about using mocks...

Answer (score 1):

Working solution in Typescript:

```
 var returnPromise = myService.method()
    returnPromise.done(() => {
        mock.verify()
    })
```